# Simplest way to integrate ADFS with ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif, adfs

I have a simple 2-page ASP.NET application that is hosted as a 'azure website'. I want to make this application secure by integrating with my company's ADFS. What is the simplest way to integrate this app with ADFS. I don't want to go through ACS if I don't have to. It looks like it is possible to make the asp.net app talk to adfs directly using WIF. 
   Can someone confirm if this will work and share any pointers to get this working?

Comment: What is ACS in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are spot-on about **not** considering ACS.

The simplest way is to just let the tooling in Visual Studio 2013 wire it up for you.

Create a new ASP.NET Web Application project and in the new project dialog, click on the Change Authentication button.

[image]

Next, select the Organizational Accounts radio button, choose On-Premises in the drop-down, and fill in your On-Premises Authority and App ID URI.

[image]

Vittorio blogged about the full experience [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) if you need more detail.

You will have to substitute in the correct URL's for your Azure Website, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks much! This worked like a charm.  I got the federation metadata of the STS and was able to successfully use it when configuring the website.  The STS asks for the federation metadata of the relying party during configuration. Do you know how to get federation metadata of the relying party?

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It helps me a lot.